# T test in image segmentation

Tags: matlab

how to use T test in image processing? i am working on image segmentation using split and merge algorithm using Matlab. to merge adjacent regions i need to t test to compare mean..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an F-test if you need to check if several samples have the same mean. The formulas you need to use depend on assumptions about your data, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test article. The F distribution can be calculated in Matlab using `fcdf`.